# Load all documents at once. Not progressively

Tags: reactjs, meteor

When I run a .fetch() command, it first returns null, then say suppose I have 100 documents and it will keep on loading from 1 to 100 and the counter keeps updating from 1 to 100 progressively. I don't want that to happen. I want all the results to be displayed at once after the fetch process has been completed.

Also, how can I display a relevant message to the user if no documents exist? The fetch method doesn't work for me since it returns 0 at first and hence "No document found" flashes for a second.

```
dbName.find({userID:"234234"}).fetch()
```

Even though the above has 100 docs, it first shows null and then keep loading the documents one by one. I want it load all at once or just return something if no docs exist.

Comment: The mongodb tag is removed from your question because the behavior you are talking about is specific to the Meteor API only and nothing to do with MongoDB itself. Please don't add it again.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want that to happen. I want all the results to be displayed at once after the fetch process has been completed

To really obtain all documents at once on the client you will have to write a Meteor Method that returns all the documents:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  'allDocs' () {
    return dbName.find({userID:"234234"}).fetch()
  }
})
```

Note, that **you have to** call fetch on the cursor to return the documents, otherwise you will face an "unhandled promise rejection error".

Then call it from the client as usually. You can even add the documents to your client side local collection without affecting allow/deny (which should be off / deny all by default):

```js
Meteor.call('allDocs', (err, documents) => {
  // ... handle err
  // all client collections have a local collection accessible via ._collection
  const localCollection = dbName._collection 
  documents.forEach(doc => localCollection.insert(doc))
})
```

**Advantages:**

- Returns all documents immediately
- Less resources consumed (no publication observers required)
- Works with caching tools, such as ground:db, to create offline-first applications

**Disadvantages:**

- You should limit the query and access to your collections using Methods as much as possible, (using mdg:validated-method) which can require much more effort than shown in this examples
- Not reactive! If you need reactivity on the client you need to include `Tracker` and reactive data-sources (`ReactiveVar` etc.) to provide some decent reactive user experience
- Manual syncing can become frustrating and is error prone

Answer (score 0):

Your question is actually about the subscription and it's state of readiness. While it is not yet ready, you can show a loading page, and once it is you can run the `.fetch()` to get the whole array. This logic could be put in your `withTracker` call, e.g.:

```js
export default withTracker((props) => {
  const sub = Meteor.subscribe('users');
  return {
    ready: sub.ready(),
    users: sub.ready() && Users.find({userID: props.userID}).fetch()
  };
})(UserComponent);
```

Then, in your component, you can decide whether to render a spinner (while `ready == false`), or the users.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not entirely clear to me in terms of tools etc (*please state which database connector lib are you using*), but firstly, given you're doing a database access, most likely, your ".fetch()" call is not a sync function but async, and also most likely, handled by a promise.

Secondly, given that you're using react, you want to set a new state only after you get all the results back.

If fetch is a promise then just do:

```
dbName.find({userID:"234234"}).fetch().then(results =>
  setState({elements:results.data}) // do your processing accordingly
}
```

By only calling setState inside the promise, you'll always have all the results fetched at that instant and only with that do you update your component state with the setState function - either using your react component class this.setState or with hooks like useState (much cleaner).

Comment: It is important in this question to note the meteor tag. That answers some of the questions you had and also indicate that this answer is off target. In meteor `.fetch()` does not return a promise but an array.